# How to make only one letter in string uppercase?NOT the first one in JS

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

```
function checkA(string1) {
    
  let a = "a";
  let A = "A";

  let text = string1;


  if (text.includes(A)) {

    return text.toLowerCase(A);

  } else if (text.includes(a)) {

    return text.toUpperCase(a);

  } else {

    return text;
  }
}


function writeWord() {

  let inputWord = document.getElementById("anyWord").value;

  let checkedWord = checkA(inputWord);

  document.getElementById("someString").innerHTML = checkedWord;
}
```

//
it making uppercase all the string.
Preferred to use upperCase & lowerCase,due to exercise terms. Not necceserily though.
//

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to change the entire string, you can replace the only letter that you need to replace using `replace` function.

By default, `replace` function only replaces the first occurrence of the string specified as a first parameter. Looks like this is exactly what you are looking for.

This can be achieved like so:

```js
function checkA(text) {    
  const a = 'a';
  const A = 'A';
  if (text.includes(A)) return text.replace(A, a);
  if (text.includes(a)) return text.replace(a, A);
  return text;
}

console.log(checkA('stack stack'));
console.log(checkA('stAck stAck'));
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.Just want to know how to do it using uppercase and lower case and ascii table. thank u very much

Comment: Can you explain why? If this is a constraint of your assignment, or work, that's fine, but such constraints or requirements should be explicit, and written in the question; please could you edit your question to add those details?

Comment: @AlexanderD you are welcome! Don't you mind picking my answer as a solution if it was useful? Thanks!

Comment: It's not neccesary, just bescause an exercise was like this.